# What is a node child process?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I'm reading a node.js project which includes the [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) library.

What exactly is a child process? Is this similar a javascript web worker?

What advantages are there to running processes in a child process rather than simply executing it normally? I'm assuming this some how gives you more access to memory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run terminal on Linux (bash process), and execute a command, for example `ls -lh /usr`, the terminal starts a child process `ls`, that writes to `stdout` all files in the current directory. Now image that instead of a terminal, you have `node.js` as a parent process. You can spawn/start a child `ls` process like this:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

> Is this similar a javascript web worker?

It might be similar to webworkers, but I don't know how webworkers are implemented under the hood in browsers. AFAIK `node` doesn't have webworkers API out of the box. But if your child process is `node.js` process, than you can view this child process something akin to `webworker`. Take a look at this [cluster API](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html).