# Run job using specific child process in Node.js

Tags: node.js, http, express, child-process

I know how to fork child process but my requirement is, I want to use this child process to do only certain job, for example when clicking the button I need to process the form data to save it like below. but this post route must be executed by the specific child process that I created not other child process nor master.

```js
app.post('/saveuser', function(){
  user.save();
})
```

Comment: Is [spawn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42327180/what-is-a-node-child-process) good enough?

Comment: Ok but I am wondering how to assign the child process to save data, Whenever the post route executes, I need to create a child process to save the data then Exit  :)

Comment: So, you want different running forks, and every fork should handle 1 kind of job, right?

Comment: Yeah exactly, but I need to use only one process for my job, I let other processes to do their own job on other things haha

Answer (score 1):

post node v11.7.0 releases 'worker_threads' module is available without experimental flag.
it is great to use for single process and multi threading purpose.
versions prior 11.7.0 you need to pass flag --experimental-worker to access it.

Visit Official Documentation  [Worker-Threads](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html)

```
/* app.js */
/* your code */

const { Worker, isMainThread, threadId, Worker, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads')

console.log('is this main process', isMainThread)

app.post('/saveuser', function(){

  let userSaveWorker = new Worker('name_of_another_script.js', { workerData: 'pass any type of data' })

  userSaveWorker.on('message', returnData => {
    // do whatever you wants to do with data returned from worker
    // return response to user
  })

  userSaveWorker.unref() // this will allow worker to terminate
  userSaveWorker.terminate() // this will forcefully terminate it
  // you can use it in message listner

  userSaveWorker.on('end', () => /* gets called when worker process gets terminated */);
})
```

now script for worker process

```
name_of_another_script.js

const { Worker, isMainThread, threadId, Worker, parentPort, workerData } = require('worker_threads')

console.log('is this main process', isMainThread)

console.log('data received from parentProcess', workerData)

/* your code */
// do process & then send message back to parent

parentPort.postMessage('your processed data or result any data type')
// this will be received in app.js as .on('message') listener
```

you can even run worker process without another script
pass function or code as a string instead of file name and pass another option { eval: true } and it'll work, you can even pass workerData as well...